# pass string to facet_grid : ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 you can pass character arguments inside a user defined function using `aes_string`.  How can you do the same for facet grid which takes a formula, not `aes`?

```
FUN <- function(data, x, y, fac1, fac2) {
     ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_point() + facet_grid(as.formula(substitute(fac1 ~ fac2)))
}


FUN(mtcars, 'hp', 'mpg', 'cyl', 'am')
```

Comment: `as.formula(paste(fac1,"~", fac2))`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`reformulate()` seems to work just fine.

```
FUN <- function(data, x, y, fac1, fac2) {
      ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point() + facet_grid(reformulate(fac2,fac1))
}

FUN(mtcars, 'hp', 'mpg', 'cyl', 'am')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Didn't know about `reformulate`.

Comment: If you want to facet only horizontally or vertically, something like `reformulate(fac1, ".")` also works.

Answer (score 6):

With *`rlang`* magic and new *`ggplot2 v3.0.0`* features you can do :

```
FUN <- function(data, x, y, fac1, fac2) {
  ggplot(data = data, aes(x = !!ensym(x), y = !!ensym(y))) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(eval(expr(!!ensym(fac1) ~ !!ensym(fac2))))
}

FUN(mtcars, 'hp', 'mpg', 'cyl', 'am')
```

Note that we don't use `aes_string`, which is soft deprecated.

Personally in these cases I like to use a function I called `glue_formula` (referencing package `glue`) :

```
glue_formula <- function(.formula, .envir = parent.frame(), ...){
  formula_chr <- gsub("\\n\\s*","",as.character(.formula)[c(2,1,3)])
  args <- c(as.list(formula_chr), .sep=" ", .envir = .envir)
  as.formula(do.call(glue::glue, args),env = .envir)
}

FUN2 <- function(data, x, y, fac1, fac2) {
  ggplot(data = data, aes(x = !!ensym(x), y = !!ensym(y))) +
    geom_point() + facet_grid(glue_formula({fac1} ~ {fac2}))
}

FUN2(mtcars, 'hp', 'mpg', 'cyl', 'am')
```

It's not tidyverse approved ([see interesting discussion here](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/108)) but it has served me well.

Comment: Thanks for the update...no knock on your solutions (especially the glue ones) but `reformulate(fac2,fac1)` seems so much cleaner and easier to reason about than `eval(expr(!!ensym(fac1) ~ !!ensym(fac2)))`

Comment: I agree, it is more flexible though, in case you have a more complex formula (which might not be relevant for facet_grid) , and it comes from lionel. The github issue is not closed so they might come up with something more satisfying.