# How to pass column name in ggplot facet_wrap in a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, lazyeval

How to pass column name of a data frame in ggplot facet_wrap or fill/colour in a function? I looked up lazyeval but didn't figure out a way.

```
x="class"
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, col=x)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(x)
```

In this example, why didn't the points get coloured by x?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588096/pass-string-to-facet-grid-ggplot2 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028353/passing-string-variable-facet-wrap-in-ggplot-using-r

Answer (score 2):

I used an example from `ggplot2::facet_wrap`. So, you can easily replace `~class` with `x` containing a character or a formulae. Example :

```
library(ggplot2)
x="class"#or ~class
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(x)
```

Comment: indeed. but how about color each facet? this doesn't seem to work. 
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, col=x)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(x)   
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by colouring  each facet ? The points or the background ?

Comment: the points, as in the snippet ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, col=x)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(x)

Comment: you should use a variable containing an integer or a factor. Try `mpg$class2 <- factor(mpg$class); ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, col=class2)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~class);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, col=as.factor(x))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~x)` ?