# Why passing a string in R ggplot2::facet_grid() works for rows but not for columns?

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588096/pass-string-to-facet-grid-ggplot2) are some workarounds for the issue, but is there a reason why you **can pass a string for `rows`** in the `ggplot2::facet_grid()` but **not for `cols`**?

This works (notice the `rows` attribute):

```
f_varname <- 'drv'

ggplot( mpg, aes( displ, cty ) ) + geom_point() +

    facet_grid( rows = f_varname )
```

But this does not (notice the `cols` attribute):

```
f_varname <- 'drv'

ggplot( mpg, aes( displ, cty ) ) + geom_point() +

    facet_grid( cols = f_varname )

# => Error: `cols` must be `NULL` or a `vars()` specification
```

Instead, you have to use the `vars()` specification for the `cols`:

```
ggplot( mpg, aes( displ, cty ) ) + geom_point() +
    
    facet_grid( cols = vars( drv ) )
```

which **can not** handle a string:

```
f_varname <- 'drv'

ggplot( mpg, aes( displ, cty ) ) + geom_point() +
    
    facet_grid( cols = vars( f_varname ) )

# =>
# Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `f_varname`.
# * Plot is missing `f_varname`
# * Layer 1 is missing `f_varname`
```

From the linked discussion, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21588225/7002525) also works with the string:

```
f_varname <- 'drv'

ggplot( mpg, aes( displ, cty ) ) + geom_point() +
    
    facet_grid( reformulate( f_varname ) )
```

Comment: From the online doc, it looks like this is a legacy feature: "For compatibility with the classic interface, rows can also be a formula...".  I'm guessing the character variable containing the name of the column can be coerced to an appropriate formula.

Comment: Thanks @Limey. Sounds like a possible explanation. These kind of features always keep me always with R, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Limey's explanation in the comments is the answer to your question, but if you're looking for a practical solution (outside of those you've linked) you can turn the string into a symbol (using `sym()`) then pass it to vars with the bang-bang operator, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
f_varname <- sym("cyl")
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(!!f_varname))
```

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot. Although I really don't understand the Bang Bang operator (nor data masking, TBH), your solution seems a more robust solution than the one using `reformulate()`